# Determine user navigation behavior

Tags: javascript

I want to determine how the user navigated to the current page he is in.

1. User type the url and press enter.
2. User press back/forward button
3. User redirected from some other page.
4. Any other possible ways of navigation. (like bookmark)

Can i determine this using javascript?

Comment: Have you looked at some of the analytic tools that do this such as lead forensics? If you want to do any logging of a user where the user is defined, you'll probably need their consent.

Comment: [HTML5 `history` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) should take care of 2 and the [referrer header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) should take care of 1 and 3.

Comment: Have you heard of [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/)?

Comment: window.performance.navigation.type helped to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `window.performance.navigation.type` object you can more or less determine how the user got there and other information. More information about the object and navigation timing can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Navigation_timing).

Comment: window.performance.navigation.type and its values ' TYPE_NAVIGATENEXT,TYPE_RELOAD,TYPE_BACK_FORWARD,TYPE_UNDEFINED' helped to solve. But i am worried about legacy browsers.